# Bash time to mysql datetime

Tags: mysql, bash, datetime, time

I am trying to get the current time in a bash script and store it in a MySql database. How can I get the current time and convert it to a format that can be saved to a MySql datetime field.

Comment: Why don't you use mysql's `NOW()`? Using **only** db server's time is a common practice

Comment: Is there a reason why you need the bash time and can't use the current-time functions in MySQL? (Darn, beaten to it!)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can write:

```
date +'%F %T'
```

which will print something like:

```
2012-03-04 11:56:54
```

(But as zerkms says, it's probably better to just use `NOW()` within MySQL.)

Comment: Worked for me, but it seems the extra spaces are not well welcomed. I have added extra space after the plus sign (+), which broke the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Equivalent of @ruakh 's answer, in expanded form:

```
date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

which will print something like:

```
2014-04-14 11:33:48
```

Useful if some of the date stamp separator characters aren't valid for one use or another.